# Download Attribute Overriding onClick <a>

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the download attribute to trigger a forced download of a song, but it seems to be overriding the onClick event. I can only do one or the other.

```
<output></output>
<input onclick="window.close()" type="button" value="Cancel"/>

<script>
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = song + ".mp3"
a.href = url
a.onclick = function(e) {
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
        'notification2.html'
    );
    notification.show();
    window.close();
}
document.getElementsByTagName("output")[0].appendChild(a);
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML = "Download"
</script>
```

How do I both trigger the download, and fire the onClick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `addEventListener`:

```
a.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
        'notification2.html'
    );
});
```

Comment: Now the event triggers, but the download doesn't.

Comment: Are you using `manifest_version:2`?  Could this possibly be a HTML/JavaScript separation problem?

Comment: If you don't have `manifest_version:2` explicitly in your manifest file, then it's not an issue. It default to `1`.

Comment: Setting it to 2 wont let the background page load. Is there a different format for version 2?

Comment: Don't use version 2 -- it requires that HTML and JS code go in separate pages, which I'll bet would require you to move a lot of stuff around.

Comment: Does the link not download at all, or just not with the specified name?

Comment: Figured it out. After trying to test with the same link for so long, I did not realize that it became invalid because of a session expiration. This works fine.